# HMTL audio with Angular JS and Material grid list not updating audio elements when visual elements update

Tags: javascript, html, audio, angular-material, angularjs-ng-repeat

I made a grid list in AngularJS Material. The grid list is generated from a JSON file using `ng-repeat`. Each tile has unique visual elements and when you click a tile it plays a unique audio file. There are four languages (English, Spanish, Chinese, Finnish). Changing languages redraws a new grid list from a JSON object unique to each language. Visually everything works perfectly. The bug is that the audio elements don't change when the language changes. You get the English audio files when you switch to Spanish, Chinese, or Finnish.

Here's my grid list:

```html
<md-grid-list md-cols="6" md-row-height="40px">
    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="consonant in targetLanguageConsonants track by $index">

      <md-button ng-show="consonant.audioButton" ng-class="[consonant.color, consonant.classAudio]" ng-click="playAudio(consonant.phoneme)" aria-label="Play audio">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="media/icons/headphones.svg" aria-label="Listen to phoneme"></md-icon>
        <audio id="{{consonant.phoneme}}">
          <source ng-src="{{consonant.audioSource}}" type="{{consonant.audioType}}"></source>
        </audio>
      </md-button>

    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
```

And here's my audio handler in the controller:

```js
  $scope.playAudio = function(phoneme) {
    $scope.targetLanguageConsonants.forEach((consonant) => {
      if (consonant.phoneme === phoneme) {
        document.getElementById(consonant.phoneme).play();;
      }
    });
  };
```

Logging the controller handler, the correct audio source file is retrieved. Inspecting the tiles, the `id` is correct for each. Everything seems to be working but the audio never changes when the language is changed. I tried `$scope.$apply()` but got the `already in progress` error.

A possible issue is that I'm unclear when to use `{{}}` double curly brackets in the `ng-repeat`. My rule is that inside `ng-` anything, the `{{}}` aren't used. But `ng-src="{{consonant.audioSource}}"` requires the `{{}}`.

This is using Chrome and FireFox. Switching to Safari, the audio files don't even play, even though the console shows that it's getting the audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best option to solve this problem its to make and directive like this:

```
app.directive('audiotrack', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { url:'=' ,id : '@',  },
    replace: true,
    template: '<audio id="{{id}}" ng-src="{{newUrl}}" controls></audio>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('url', function (newVal, oldVal) {
           if (newVal !== undefined) {
               scope.newUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

and in your component view in the ng-repeat part just add your directive:

```
playing Audio Nº {{indexAudio}}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="audio in myAudios track by $index">
      <button ng-click="playAudio(audio,$index)" aria-label="Play audio">Play {{$index}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div audiotrack url="selectedAudioUrl" id="myAudioPlayer"></div>
```

I made a working example , directive its define in app.js file, and then the rest of the example its over Home view:

live demo link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-7bmth3

Peace my perros :)